# how to use iterator?

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, if-statement, iterator

I am trying to change the characters in the string using iterator. It changes the characters before white space but it is removing the characters after that white space.

Whats happening wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s;
    cout<<"Enter a string : ";
    cin>>s;

    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end() && !isspace(*it);++it)
      *it = toupper(*it);

    cout<<s; // capitalize the current character
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Enter a string : abc abc 
>   ABC

Answer (score 5):

The condition in the for statement is incorrect

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end() && !isspace(*it);++it)
 *it = toupper(*it);
```

The loop stops its iterations when a white space is encountered.

You should the second subexpression move in an if statement within the body of the loop. For example

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end();++it)
 if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )*it) ) *it = toupper( ( unsigned char )*it);
```

And instead of the statement

```
cin>>s;
```

use

```
std::getline( std::cin, s );
```

Comment: You should also show him the C++14 way: `for (auto & c : s) if(...) c = ...;`

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow I want the loop to stop after encountering white space. I want to know that why the characters after white space are being removed? And I don't want to go upto the end of the string. I just want to change the characters before the white space.

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't with the iterator. The problem is how you're reading the input:

```
 cin>>s;
```

This will read a single word, i.e. it will skip leading whitespace, and read everything until the next whitespace. If you want to read an entire line use:

```
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::toupper);
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the OP's problem and won't compile if the locale version of `std::toupper` is visible.